# How to backpropagate transposed convolution?

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, convolution, transposed-convolution

I'm currently learning Convolutional Neural Networks and am stuck on trying to figure out how to compute gradients in a layer that uses transposed convolution. Also, how do I calculate the gradients if I use padding=1 and stride=2?

Thanks to this article "https://hideyukiinada.github.io/cnn_backprop_strides2.html" I was able to figure out how to calculate gradients in normal convolution and all that remains for me is to figure out how to calculate them in transposed convolution.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal convolution network you can easily calculate the derivative of X*K=Y with respect to X or K by writing down the formula of each cell in Y and thus you can easily derive Y with respect to X or K.

derivative in normal convolution:

dL/dX = K (fully convolved 180) with dL/dY

dL/dK = X (convolved) with dL/dY

But in the transposed convolution network it is exactly the opposite. The calculation of the derivative in a normal convolution is very similar to the normal calculation of transposed convolution and in the same idea the derivative of the transposed convolution is similar to the normal convolution between X or K and the output. And of course you can write down the formula of each cell in Y and derive with respect to X or K and see it for yourself.

derivative of transposed convolution:

dL/dX = K (convolved) with Y

dL/dK = X (convolved) with Y